Closed form solution for the linear acceleration of a particle on 3D rotating object given momentum and MoI?
Is there a closed-form solution for the linear acceleration of a particle on a rigid body undergoing some arbitrary rotation in 3D with no external forces, given its angular momentum vector and its moment of inertia matrix? The object may be undergoing free precession for example.

It's not quite clear what your question means, you should be a lot more descriptive and maybe provide an example diagram showing what you mean.
